# How can I get line numbers where changes where introduced?

Tags: git, diff

I have a bunch of text files. Some changes were introduced. I need to get the list of line numbers in the original files where changes (any, editing/deletion/insertion) happened. I need it to only be line numbers, no actual changes in the text allowed to be shown.

I can put files into two folders or create git repo for with two commits for it.

I tried to use `git diff` but failed to find appropriate option. What are my other options?

EDIT:
I used `git diff -U0 | egrep "^\+{3}|^@@" | grep -Eo '^\+.*|^@@ [-0-9,]*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command in your shell:

```
git diff -U0 | egrep "^\+{3}|^@@"
```

After that it takes just a little bit of parsing to get the line numbers that changed.

If you don't care about knowing what files the changes are in, try:

```
git diff -U0 | egrep "^@@"
```